# NESTED SELECT, UNION, LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query involving three tables:

1. `Employee`
2. `Attendance`
3. `Category`

where

- the PK of `Employee` is `Id`;
- the PK of `Category` is `Staff_id`;
- the PK of `Attendance` is `attendance_Id`;
- `Employee` has a foreign key `Staff` referencing `Category.Staff_id`;
- `Attendance` has a foreign key `Id` referencing `Employee.Id`

I need to modify my query to provide an additional column `position` drawn from a fourth table, `Position`, and to group the results by `Position.position` and `Employee.Staff`.  I cannot modify any table's structure or content.

Result rows should look like this, where "Driver" corresponds to `Staff = 2`:

## ### Position | TotalEmp  | TotalAttendance  |  TimeIn    |  TimeOut

```
 Driver           5               5               8.00am       6.00pm
```

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT D.TotalEmp, D.TotalAttendance, D.Timein, D.TimeOut
FROM (
  SELECT B.TotalEmp, B.TimeIn, B.TimeOut FROM (
    SELECT
      (SELECT COUNT (distinct Id) FROM Employee WHERE Staff = 2) AS TotalEmp,
      (
        SELECT COUNT(id)
        FROM Attendance Q
        WHERE
          id IN (SELECT (Id) FROM Employee WHERE Staff = 2) 
          AND  CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(nvarchar(10), Q.timeInDate, 103), 103) = '20/11/2014'
      ) AS TotalAttendance, 
      (
        SELECT MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),I.timeInDate,108))
        FROM Attendance I
        WHERE
          CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(nvarchar(10), I.timeInDate, 103), 103) = '20/11/2014'
          AND I.id IN (SELECT (Id) FROM Employee WHERE Staff = 2)
      ) Timein,
      (
        SELECT
          MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),O.timeOutDate,108))
        FROM Attendance O
        WHERE
          CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(nvarchar(10), O.timeOutDate, 103), 103) = '20/11/2014'
          AND O.id IN (SELECT (Id) FROM Employee WHERE Staff = 2)
      ) TimeOut
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT (id) FROM Attendance) 
  ) B 

  UNION

  SELECT C.TotalEmp, C.Time, C.TimeOut FROM (
    SELECT
      (SELECT COUNT (distinct Id) FROM Employee WHERE Staff = 1) AS TotalEmployee, 
      ( 
        SELECT COUNT(id)
        FROM Attendance R
        WHERE
          id IN (SELECT (Id) FROM Employee WHERE Staff = 1) 
          AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(nvarchar(10), R.timeInDate, 103), 103) = '20/11/2014'
      ) AS TotalAttendance,
      (
        SELECT MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), T.timeInDate, 108))
        FROM Attendance T
        WHERE
          CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(nvarchar(10), T.timeInDate, 103), 103) = '20/11/2014'
          AND T.id IN (SELECT (Id) FROM Employee WHERE Staff = 1)
      ) Timein,
      (
        SELECT MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),X.timeOutDate,108))
        FROM Attendance X
        WHERE
          CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(nvarchar(10), X.timeOutDate, 103), 103) = '20/11/2014'
          AND X.id IN (SELECT (Id) FROM Employee WHERE Staff = 1)
      ) TimeOut
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT (id) FROM Attendance) 
  ) C
) D

GROUP BY D.TotalEmp, D.TotalAttendance, D.Timein, D.TimeOut
```

How can I modify my query to produce the required result?

Comment: I am not understanding how you want to group your results. You say you want another column from a table called position but how does it relate to the other tables?

Comment: MSB: The result should be based on Position. E.g:                                           Position is Programmer, Total employee for that position is 10 and the total attendance for that position is 5, followed by earliest time in and time out.  The result should be based on staff category and position

Comment: I think posting a mock up of the tables you are using could help me and other better see your structure.

Comment: MSB, Kindly refer to my mockup table..

Comment: @ChloeBenjiman, you need to explain how rows from table `Position` are related to rows from table `Employee` and / or rows from table `Category`.  That is, how does one know which is the position that goes with any given row of your current query result?

Comment: @ChloeBenjiman, additionally, I don't understand how the results could be grouped by position and staff when staff is not among the selected columns.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Oh, I forgot to mention, the positionId (PK) of table position is also acts as the foreign key in table Employee namely position_id.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I want to produce a report which is grouped by position and staff. Staff is devided into two categories: 1 and 2.

Comment: @ChloeBenjiman "I want to produce a report which is grouped by position and staff" -- yes, but *where is `staff` in your results*?  You cannot group by data that are not part of the results, at least not in the sense of an SQL `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, what should I do? I can fetch all the positions in table position. I can't however grouped the rest of the result based on that particular position. I also can determine the staff category for each position. I can't think of any sql design that can satisfy these requirements

Comment: @ChloeBenjiman I'm analyzing your existing query.  What are the data types of `Attendance.timeInDate` and `Attendance.timeOutDate`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Datetime

Comment: @JohnBolinger, "each Position row corresponds to exactly one possible value of Employee.Staff"-Yes, you are right. There are 3 tables involved:  Table 1: Employee. PK: Id FK: Staff and position_id.  Table 2: Position. PK: attendance_Id FK: id (Id of Table Employee) . Table 3: Category. PK: Staff_id. Note: positionId belongs to table Attendance. positionId(Attendance) = position_id(Employee)

Comment: @ChloeBenjiman, now you're confusing me.  `positionId` belongs to table `Attendance`, not table `Position`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Sorry, it belongs to table position.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, do you anything about this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074366/use-panel-to-manipulate-dynamic-controls

Comment: @ChloeBenjiman, nope, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you'll forgive me for saying that your original original query is pretty horrible.  It uniformly performs subqueries where joins would be more appropriate, and it has multiple subqueries that beg to be factored out as common table expressions, or even simply as top-level aggregates.  It also expresses some `WHERE` predicates that are wholly redundant with the foreign-key constraints on the base tables.  And it uses opaque table aliases instead of meaningful ones.

The original query also has some very suspicious structure:

- subqueries `C` and `D` each select from table `Employee`, but *none* of the selected columns actually come from that table.  All are the results of uncorrelated aggregate (sub)queries, so subqueries `C` and `D` will each provide as many rows as there are `Employee` rows, all identical (per-subquery).  Then all those unneeded duplicates are removed again when the `UNION` operator eliminates duplicate rows.
- you have a `GROUP BY` clause on the outermost query, but no aggregate functions in that query's selection list.  Perhaps you wanted to `ORDER BY` those columns instead, but if not then the `GROUP BY` is altogether useless.
- You are converting dates to strings to compare them; that's not necessarily wrong for equality comparisons, but it's inefficient.  It *is* wrong for greater-than and less-than comparisons, however, and therefore it's also wrong for use with `MIN()` and `MAX()`.  It will work well enough, though, to fool you by producing the right results in some cases.
- You perform a `UNION` of two subqueries with identical structure, differing only in some query predicates.  This begs to be combined into a single query.

It will surely help to start by simplifying the original query.  It looks like this will produce the same data, except with a `Staff` column added and possibly in a different order:

```
SELECT
  emp.Staff,
  COUNT(DISTINCT emp.id) AS TotalEmp,
  COUNT(DISTINCT att.id) AS TotalAttendance,
  MIN(att.timeInDate) AS TimeIn,
  MAX(att.timeOutDate) AS TimeOut,
FROM
  Employee emp
  LEFT JOIN Attendance att ON att.Id = emp.Id
WHERE 
  CAST(att.timeInDate AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, '20/11/2014', 103)
  AND (emp.Staff = 1 OR emp.Staff = 2)
GROUP BY emp.Staff
```

Note that it does group by `Staff`; this eliminates the need for a `UNION`, while still preserving the per-Staff aggregate values (indeed, that's the whole point of `GROUP BY`).  Note, too, that if `1` and `2` are the only possible values for `Employee.Staff`, or if you're ok with getting results for other values, too, then you can simplify further by removing the the `WHERE` condition restricting the results to only those values.

Note also that your `Datetime` values are converted to `Date` to strip off the time portion; this is much more efficient than formatting them as strings.  Your literal date string is converted to a `Date` for comparison (using format 103).

That serves as a much better starting point, as the structure of the data and the nature of the grouping are clear.  And it is so much simpler!  Now if you want to split the groups differently, it's pretty easy to do so.

In particular, something like this should do what you want:

```
SELECT
  pos.position AS position,
  COUNT(DISTINCT emp.id) AS TotalEmp,
  COUNT(DISTINCT att.id) AS TotalAttendance,
  MIN(att.timeInDate) AS TimeIn,
  MAX(att.timeOutDate) AS TimeOut,
FROM
  Employee emp
  JOIN Position pos ON emp.position_id = pos.positionId
  LEFT JOIN Attendance att ON att.Id = emp.Id
WHERE
  CAST(att.timeInDate AS DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, '20/11/2014', 103)
GROUP BY pos.position
```

That relies on the fact that each position is associated with exactly one `Staff` value, so that it gains nothing to group by `Staff` as well.